# "help someone do" vs. "help someone to do"

Tags: to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

Which sentence is correct and why?

> 1. Could you help the carnivore cut his meat?
> 2. Could you help the carnivore to cut his meat?

Answer (score 2):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/help-somebody-to-do

Both are correct. People use 'Help one do something' and also 'Help one to do something'.